# How to run DotMemory tests inside Rider?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider, dotmemory

How do I run DotMemory Unit tests (NUnit) inside of rider? I am able to run those tests with teamcity by specifying the dotMemory support but somehow I am unable to run those tests inside of Rider.

Comment: Not supported in this release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference NUnit, reference dotMemory Unit, write test and run it "under dotMemory Unit" just like in Resharper.
What problem do you experience?

P.S. Only on Windows, of course...

[image]

Comment: I have references dotMemory.Unit.dll, Jetbrains.dotMemory.Core.dll, JetBrains.Profiler.Windows.Api.dll and copied them to the same folder where the csproj file lies. When I try to run the dotMemory unit test it tells me "File not found". When I run it directly with "Run tests" it tells me "the test was run without the suppor for dotMemory Unit".  I am running Rider 2017.1 on Windows 10 x64. Is this small icon the only way to run tests under dotMemory Unit at the moment? I'd like to setup a suite, such that I can run press "run all tests" and have it run the memory tests under dotMemory.

Comment: @NoxMortem
You should reference this nuget, because it contains "server" side of dotMemory Unit which runs unit test runner under memory profiling in order to obtain memory data.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/JetBrains.DotMemoryUnit/

Comment: You are completly right, it is possible to run test under dotMemory in Rider 2017.1. However, it looks like there is a bug related to either NUnit 3.5 (most likely) or DotMemory (2.3.20160517.113140) or Rider (2017.1).

After removal of both NUnit and DotMemory and installing NUnit 3.7 and DotMemory again it worked as described.

Comment: I'm glad that now it works for you but still don't understand why did you reference Jetbrains.dotMemory.Core.dll JetBrains.Profiler.Windows.Api.dll.
All and only you need is nuget, nothing will work w/o it.

Comment: Is that the only way?  Is there a way to run all tests in solution under dotMemory?

Comment: @BanksySan For now it's impossible to run all tests in solution/project under dotMemory Unit. We are working on it.